# Rename displayName and CN from givenName and surName with Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I need to reconcile the `displayName` and `CN` attributes to the `givenName` and `surName` fields in AD.

Is it possible to take `givenName` and `surName` and rename both the `displayName` and `CN` using Powershell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Powershell really shines for clean-up tasks like this.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties cn,displayName

foreach ( $u in $allUsers | Where-Object { ($_.givenName) -and ($_.surName) } ) {
    $fn = $u.givenName.Trim()
    $ln = $u.surName.Trim()
    Write-Host $fn $ln
    Set-ADUser -Identity $u -DisplayName "$fn $ln" -GivenName "$fn" -SurName "$ln" -PassThru |
        Rename-ADObject -NewName "$fn $ln"
}
```

Caveats:

1. I'm `Trim()`ing the `givenName` and `surName` to remove leading/trailing spaces. We commit these two back to the account, as well as correcting `displayName` and `cn`.
2. Scope your `-Filter` in `Get-ADUser` to only gather the users you want. The `*` will grab *everyone* in the domain, including built-ins, admins, etc. This probably isn't what you want. :)
3. The `Where-Object` portion of the `foreach` will skip user objects that do not have both a `givenName` and `surName` attribute.
4. If you need to play with the renamed user object, add a `-PassThru` to the end of the `Rename-ADObject` line and the object will be passed back to you.